# Using + to concat string in Java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have a huge string as below :

```
String str = "aaaaaaa" 
        + "bbbbbbbb" 
        + "cccccccc" 
    .... 

        + "zzzzzzzz";  // about 200 lines long
```

Is it a big waste of memory? Will it be better to put it in one line or use `StringBuilder`?
This is done to create a long sql.

Comment: A better question would be, why are you concatenating that many lines?

Comment: @Makoto How else will you do it?

Comment: Since you're using it for the purpose of building SQL queries, I would look into a more concise API to create that, like the [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. The compiler will perform the concatenation *at compile time* if all your strings are constant (as they are in your question). So that ends up performing *better* than the `StringBuilder` version.

It will use `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) to perform the concatenation of any *non-constant* parts otherwise.

So the compiled version of:

```
String x = "a" + "b";
```

should be *exactly* the same as:

```
String x = "ab";
```

Note that the "non-constant" parts can mean that you can sometimes get (very minor) extra efficiencies using bracketing wisely. For example:

```
int value = ...;
String x = "a" + value + "b" + "c";
```

... is less efficient than:

```
int value = ...;
String x = "a" + value + ("b" + "c");
```

... as the first appends `"b"` and `"c"` separately. The efficient version is equivalent tO:

```
int value = ...;
String x = "a" + value + "bc";
```

I can't remember *ever* seeing this used as a legitimate micro-optimization, but it's at least a point of interest.

Comment: Doesn't / shouldn't the compiler do that micro-optimization for you anyway? Or, to look at it from another angle, can there be any value of `foo` for which `(foo + "a") + "b"` would ever be different from `foo + "ab"`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Not that I can think of - but that was what I observed with the standard javac. I *think* it would be a valid optimization though.

Comment: Is there way to not perform the optimization?

Answer (score 4):

In current versions of Java, each `+` (concatenation) operation gets automatically compiled to a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) `append()` operation. However, if it's inside a loop, it will create a new `StringBuilder` for each iteration, negating its effect - so you'd be better of managing the `StringBuilder` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

No. The compiler will optimise this for you into a `StringBuilder`.

Edit: As Louis Wasserman points out, it will also combine String literals for you, so the statement above would just be a single String at compile time.

Comment: Not quite correct.  If all these are literal strings, the compiler will just optimize it into a single `String` without using a `StringBuilder` at all.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK JVM internally has a pool of Strings, every String you create is stored there, discarding the oldest/least used ones (im not sure how it chooses which ones). If you explictly invoke String.intern() youre telling the JVM to put the String in the pool.

when you concatenate two Strings using + you end up with three Strings in the pool.
If you concatenate a + b + c, you woyld end up with 5 Strings (a, b, ab, c, abc)

At least thats what i recall on older JVM versions, but Luiggi is quite probably right, that on newer ones its internally optimized

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
String str = "aaaaaaa" + "bbbbbbbb" + "cccccccc";
```

gets transformed at compile time to:

```
String str = (new StringBuilder()).append("aaaaaaa").append("bbbbbbbb").append("cccccccc").toString();
```

So, there doesn't appear to be any difference in using StringBuilder.

There's a very nice article that closely compares the performance of concat (+) against StringBuilder and StringBuffer, complete with line graphs:

[StringBuilder vs StringBuffer vs String.concat - Done Right](http://kaioa.com/node/59).